# Loop through json data from database on php page

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've this column in database table:

```
value=[
       {"srno":1,
        "name":"Gaspari Aminolast ",
        "quantity":"2",
        "price":"2920.0000",
        "total_bill":5840
       },
       {"srno":2,
        "name":"Gaspari Amino Max ",
         "quantity":"2",
         "price":"2640.0000",
         "total_bill":5280
       },
       {"srno":3,
        "name":"Myofusion 10Lbs",
        "quantity":"2",
        "price":"8400.0000",
        "total_bill":16800}
]
```

And my php code is:

```
<?php
    $getbill="select value from $tbl where bill_id='$_GET[id]' ";
    $result=mysql_query($getbill)or die(mysql_error());
    $results = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $results[] = json_decode($row['value']);
    }
    print_r($results);
    foreach($results as $key=>$value){
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['srno'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['quantity'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['price'];?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $value['total_bill'];?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?PHP   
    }
?>
```

I'm confused with how I loop through this and print all it contains.

print_r() :

```
Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
         [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                       [srno] => 1 
                       [name] => Gaspari Aminolast 
                       [quantity] => 2 
                       [price] => 2920.0000 
                       [total_bill] => 5840 
                  ) 
          [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                       [srno] => 2 
                       [name] => Gaspari Amino Max 
                       [quantity] => 2 
                       [price] => 2640.0000 
                       [total_bill] => 5280 
                  ) 
          [2] => stdClass Object ( 
                       [srno] => 3 
                       [name] => Myofusion 10Lbs 
                       [quantity] => 2 
                       [price] => 8400.0000 
                       [total_bill] => 16800 
                   ) 
       )
)
```

Comment: show the result of print_r(). Wrap it in <pre> tags.

Comment: Do you print these records in a HTML `<table>` object? Also, normally a table has one body and will be filled with multiple rows.

Comment: print_r() : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [srno] => 1 [name] => Gaspari Aminolast [quantity] => 2 [price] => 2920.0000 [total_bill] => 5840 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [srno] => 2 [name] => Gaspari Amino Max [quantity] => 2 [price] => 2640.0000 [total_bill] => 5280 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [srno] => 3 [name] => Myofusion 10Lbs [quantity] => 2 [price] => 8400.0000 [total_bill] => 16800 ) ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use second argument in [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function,set it to TRUE to get as array

```
$json='[{"srno":1,"name":"Gaspari Aminolast ","quantity":"2","price":"2920.0000","total_bill":5840},{"srno":2,"name":"Gaspari Amino Max ","quantity":"2","price":"2640.0000","total_bill":5280},{"srno":3,"name":"Myofusion 10Lbs","quantity":"2","price":"8400.0000","total_bill":16800}]';


echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode($json,TRUE));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [srno] => 1
            [name] => Gaspari Aminolast 
            [quantity] => 2
            [price] => 2920.0000
            [total_bill] => 5840
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [srno] => 2
            [name] => Gaspari Amino Max 
            [quantity] => 2
            [price] => 2640.0000
            [total_bill] => 5280
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [srno] => 3
            [name] => Myofusion 10Lbs
            [quantity] => 2
            [price] => 8400.0000
            [total_bill] => 16800
        )

)
```

Comment: Why, **whats wrong with Objects**. You have to assume that if they were put on the database as Objects there was a good reason.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nothing wrong with object,its good to use objects ,just answered how a json string decoded to array only.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, now I reformatted the value column, each value column contains a JSON string denoting an array of objects.

So for each `value` you store in the `$results` array you neeed to do another loop to examine the inner array of objects. Like so:

```
<?php
    $getbill="select value from $tbl where bill_id='{$_GET[id]}' ";
    $result=mysql_query($getbill)or die(mysql_error());
    $results = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $results[] = json_decode($row['value']);
    }
    print_r($results);

    echo '<tbody>';

    foreach($results as $value) :
        foreach( $value as $object) :
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $object->srno;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $object->name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $object->quantity;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $object->price;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $object->total_bill;?></td>
    </tr>

<?php   
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
?>
</tbody>
```

I also moved the `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` outside the loop as that would also have caused a problem with your layout.

Answer (score 0):

The array your trying to loop over seems to be in another array.
Try this or @RiggsFolly's answer

```
<table>
<?php
    $getbill="select value from $tbl where bill_id='$_GET[id]' ";
    $result=mysql_query($getbill)or die(mysql_error());
    $results = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $results = json_decode($row['value']);
    }
    print_r($results);
    foreach($results as $key=>$value){
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['srno'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['quantity'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['price'];?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $value['total_bill'];?></td>
    </tr>

<?PHP   
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you missed the inner array of objects.

Comment: The inner array is brought outside by losing the [] in the while loop. The mysql result once json_decoded is the whole array he is trying to output and by using the [] he put them in another array

Comment: Yea, it also looses all but the last `json_decode($row['value']);` in the result set loop

Comment: Yes but purely based on his printr, there is only one record. This is why I said to try either of our answers because mine assumes his mistake was to treat a single result as an array and yours assumes his mistake was to not dig into the array enough.

Comment: So remove the while loop. Although the OP may have just reduced the actual data for the sake of brevity. Remember the old adage, `assumption is the mother of all &^%$£""!`

Comment: No offense intended but if OP saw this outer array issue I do not think this question would have been posted so I doubt he has done any reduction of data and the fact that he did not notice this issue tells me he did not know what format he expected the data to be in and so options would be a good thing. As for optimizing by removing the while loop there is no need to change that much if he just wishes to see the fix. Plus, I could say the same for your fix. Why two loops?

Comment: Ok it was not my intension to get into an arguement. My original comment was intended to help you improve your answer. Just for reference I ran your code and the result was `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\PHP_SOURCE\tst.php` So now I am done with this, as it the questioner, who has taken what he needed and not even bothered to say "Thanks for all the Fish"

Comment: That's very possible. My code is one change from the OP's. It was never run. If the data being decoding are objects then both mine and his would break. I simply pointed out the issue OP asked about. My answer is an answer not a fix. I don't have a php environment with me to actually run it :)